# Is there anything I can buy to use downward tilt on Sony A7 on Tripod?

Tags: tripod, sony

With Sony A7 line cameras, and from what I'm reading other Sony cameras as well there's a real design flaw where you can't use the screen at its downward tilt angle when on a tripod.

I've found a [makeshift solution](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3601160) but it seems somewhat labor intensive. I am wondering if there's a better adapter or small plate of some sort I can just buy for a few dollars instead?

Shooting manual focus so really need to be able to see at least the screen if not the viewfinder. Might end up bringing something to stand on instead but that's pretty silly too.

**Update:** To be clear I just purchased a Benro Travel Flat A1192TB0 that comes with an Arca Swiss style Quick Release Plate PU-50 (I believe, pretty new to this tripod / tripod head stuff).

Here is with the QR PU-50

[image]

Compared to how far it can tilt down without the obstruction and what I'm looking to obtain while on a tripod

[image]

Comment: You could use a Canon or Nikon lens, with a Metabones adapter that has an Arca foot / 1/4-20 tripod screw hole. Probably not what you're looking for... =\

Comment: @scottbb that's a rather expensive solution but it is an idea that might lead me to some other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sunwayfoto has an Arca-copmatible L-plate](http://www.sunwayfoto.com/e_goodsDetail.aspx?gid=1238) (similar to the Really Right Stuff plate)¹. Apparently it introduced at $60, but as of 2016-03-02, I was able to find it for < $20 USD on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ISJP2IK).

Notably, the Sunwayfoto plate appears to allow more downward angle of the LCD than the RRS plate does.

Articles describing the Sunwayfoto plate:

- [original PSL-a7 plate](http://www.scvphotoideas.com/2013/12/new-sunwayfoto-custom-plate-modular-l.html)
- [improved PSL-a7II plate](http://www.scvphotoideas.com/2014/03/improved-sunwayfoto-custom-modular-l.html) (not for Sony a7 Mark II camera. Confusing product naming, I know).

¹ Note: often times, "Arca-compatible" is a loose definition. If you use a lever-action Arca-type clamp, this plate might not be compatible (according to some of the Amazon reviews). However, if your Arca-type clamp uses a screw knob to tighten the jaws, this plate (or *any* Arca-type plate) will work fine.

Comment: Well now I dont know if yours or MichaelT's deserves the Accepted mark. That improved one looks terrific considering it even shows it with the screen angled down. Is there anything I need to watch out for as far as making sure its compatible with the ball head my tripod came with?

Comment: I just checked on your Benro tripod w/ ballhead. If the images are correct, your ballhead has a screw-type clamp. You should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Its a matter of what tripod mount you are using. Some are bigger than others.  While a bogen hex plate could potentially give you issues, an L bracket from something like Really Right Stuff ([Sony A7 L plate](http://www.reallyrightstuff.com/BA7-L-Set-L-plate-for-A7)) appears to be designed so that it has a smaller than camera base plate on it.

[image]

I'm going to point out that this is not a "few dollars" and if you are asking this question, you likely don't have an arca-swiss style quick release plate tripod head.

Thats just one quick release plate.  There are many others in the area style that are small.  For example:

[image]

is a small generic plate on a rather small camera.

There are some rather small QR plates out there from Arca-Swiss such as a 32mm x 32mm plate ([b&h](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/663108-REG/Arca_Swiss_802260_Slidefix_QR_Camera_Plate.html)) and a 48mm x 32mm plate ([b&h](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/663110-REG/Arca_Swiss_802265_Slidefix_QR_Camera_Plate.html)).  Given the option I'd be looking at the larger of those two plates because it provides more of a base for the camera to rest on (though I have to admit that I don't have a Arca-Swiss head to look at (I've got Bogen RC-0s which I know won't work for you at all) nor a Sony camera to measure to check on the tolerances).

Get a good tripod and a good quick release system and you won't have this problem. There are more than enough QR plates out there for the Arca-Swiss system that you will find *something* that works precisely.  And given the funds, I'd really check with the RRS option mentioned at top because it is designed exactly for that camera.

---

That said, an old search finds [extending the 1/4" screw on tripod heads](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2802649).  A home improvement store should be able to get you a longer screw and you put a few bolts and washers on it in hopes of providing enough support.

That last bit is key... and something you are going to have to watch out for.  You are trying to move a rather heavy camera up a bit - so that it isn't in contact with the tripod head.  This means that the stresses on the screw itself will be greater. You risk breaking off the screw in the camera with any solution like this.

Comment: I just bought a Benro Travel Flat which included an Arca-Swiss Style PU-50 Universal Quick Release Plate. Would there be some other Arca-Swiss PU Quick Release Plate that would fix this?

Comment: If you have an arca-swiss style QR plate as an option, something like the [32mmx32mm](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/663108-REG/Arca_Swiss_802260_Slidefix_QR_Camera_Plate.html) would probably fit on the camera without problem (the 48mmx32 would probably also work and better).  I don't have an acra-swiss qr head to test with (I'm invested in bogen hex plate heads) nor a sony to measure precisely the dimensions at issue. I will point out the RRS L bracket is probably the best long term option and you can check with them about the LCD display.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both of those. If you want to edit your answer to include your comment then I'd be happy to mark it accepted.

Comment: Aside, give [this](http://500th.net/articles/arca-swiss-quick-releases) a read for the buy it and don't look back.

Comment: 100% agreed @MichaelT. I went RRS awhile back, and have not regretted it one bit. I think camera-body -specific L-plates are one of the best things to keep everything tight, minimize twisting, keeping everything rock solid.

Comment: @scottbb *Personally* I use the bogen hex plate (RC-0) because I fell in love with the 3047 head. Its a beast of a pan tilt head but really does a good job of "this is tightened down on this axis, it *isn't* going to move". I never found a pan-tilt that I liked for arca heads that was affordable when I was in the 'buying tripod heads' phase. The [C1 cube](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1029552-REG/arca_swiss_8501003_1_c1_cube_geared_head.html) is nice, but certainly not in the affordable range.

Comment: I'm going to mark the other answer correct mostly because its $17.00 so if it works, great. If not I'll unaccept it and have to shell out for the RRS one at $175 and change the accepted answer. Really appreciate the help and links though!

Comment: @Ryan ... so you're saying accepted answers can be bought? ;-)

Comment: @scottbb apparently, only cheaply... or if I was going to supplement the additional $158.

Comment: Dont know if you're serious or not but had to pick an answer. Both of you were very helpful. The Sunwayfoto is less expensive and as noted is supposed to have better downward viewing angle than the RRS plate. Since thats my main concern than if it does work its probably a better option even if the RRS one is a tighter fit. (cc: @scottbb )

Comment: @Ryan sorry, we were just kidding around. =)  Certainly, MichaelT's answer is better, more instructive and informative. But in this particular case, it's entirely understandable that my answer fits your needs better, because as you said, the LCD angle was the entire motivation for the question.

Comment: I've heard it said "a novice photographer debates Canon vs Nikon; an intermediate debates Leica vs Hasselblad; a master discusses tripods."  My take away from that was "when you get down to it - its the tripod and head that matters - not the other stuff."  I spent ~$300 on plastic tripods that broke before I bought a 3021 leg set and that 3047 head... which was only slightly more expensive than the plastic I had bought and discarded... and I still have it (not going to comment on the tripods I bought *since* - carbon fiber is light on the back and heavy on the wallet).

Comment: well than we're all clearly masters! :D